# Can I travel to Macedonia and Albania on Schengen visa? Do I need transit visa for Germany if my stay is less than 4 hours within the airport?

Tags: schengen, transit, germany, albania, macedonia

I am a Pakistani national on a student visa till July 2016. I will travel with my family who are British Nationals.

Can I travel to Macedonia and Albania on Schengen visa? Do I need transit visa for Germany if my stay is less than 4 hours within the airport?

Comment: You first question "Can I travel to Macedonia and Albania on Schengen visa?" can easily be answered by a web search. Go from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Pakistani_citizens and follow the links.

Comment: @DCTLib the page you cite does not answer the question.  In particular, it does not discuss which visa a Pakistani citizen must hold to enter Albania or Macedonia.

Comment: What student visa do you hold?  Is it a type C Schengen visa our something else? How long are you planning to stay in these countries?

Comment: As far as my research since yesterday, I can travel to Albania and Macedonia on Multiple type C Schengen visa. 

Next question is would Greece offer me Multiple Type C Schegen Visa. I intend to go to Greece for a couple of days and Macedonia/Albania for 4 days each.

Thanks guys

Comment: @AsjadKhan You're on a student visa where?

Comment: I am currently on Student visa in UK.

Comment: @phoog Actually, the page does provide information which visa is needed. You just need to follow the link on the page. And that link tells you that under certain conditions, type C Schengen visa are sufficient.

Comment: @DCTLib which of the hundreds of links on that page must one follow to find that information?

Comment: @phoog The page is for visa requirements for citizens of Pakistan. There is a big table with countries. As the OP wants to visit Macedonia, the important row of the table is the "Macedonia" row, which says "Visa Required [105]" You click on "[105]" and it will bring you to the respective position in the reference list. Click on the reference, and you you will be redirected to a page with all the details, including all "substitute visa" that allow Entry into Macedonia.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information provided in the comments, your plan is to visit Greece, Albania, and Macedonia on a single trip.

While a multi-entree type C Schengen visa seems to be sufficient for entry into Albania and Macedonia, note that this is a special case. Macedonia and Albania are independent from the Schengen area, and it is thus their choice whom they let and in whom they don't. The rule that travelers with a Schengen visa can enter without visa is just to make their life easier by assumiing that if a traveller is "trusted enough" for a multiple-entry  Schengen visa, this seems to be good enough for them.

Yet, it is very unlikely that a Schengen state embassy will issue a visa for the purpose of visiting a non-Schengen state. You could always apply for a Macedonian and Albanian visa separately.

There is the remote chance that the Greek embassy (whom you would address your application to as Greece is the primary destination of your planned trip in the Schengen area) will issue a multiple-entry type C visa that is valid long enough anyway. You could apply for what you want, provide a correct itinery, and explain why you want you visa to be valid for at least 5 days after all of these countries have been visited. If you are in luck and the visa officer doesn't see a problem with that, you may get what you asked for. Especially if you are a first-time applicant for a Schengen visa, I wouldn't bet on this to work, however. After all, it is not the task of the Greek visa officer to decide who is allowed to enter Macedonia or Albania. So be prepared for making seperate applications for Macedonia and Albania.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can travel in Albania and Macedonia with Schengen Visa. Enjoy your trip.

Comment: This is not correct. Neither Albania nor Macedonia are in the Schengen zone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Membership.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier there are several countries that are not in the Schengen zone, but they allow schengen-visa holders to enter the country. http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders

Comment: Ok, My mistake, I'm sorry. Still, the downvote stands. This is not at all obvious, it doesn't deserve an 'of course'.